# How can I create a Google Tag Manager rule which fires based on the presence of a DOM element with no ID?

Tags: macros, google-tag-manager

I'm working on a client's ecommerce website where, when somebody signs up successfully to the site, a success message () is displayed within an unordered list element ().

I would like to create a Google Tag Manager Rule which fires when this success message has loaded on the page, but can't figure out how - and would love your help if you can spare a min!

Based on my readying (primarily Simo Ahava - http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/macro-guide-google-tag-manager/) I've tried creating a DOM Element macro where the ElementID is "success-msg", and then using that to create the following rule:

```
{{url}} - ends with - /artistsignup/index/index
{{success message}} - greater than - 0
{{event}}} - equals - gtm.load
```

However this doesn't seem to be working.

Any advice would be very much appreciated, thank you so much!

```
<div class="col-main">
<ul class="messages">
<li class="success-msg">
<ul>
<li>
<span>Thank you for signing up.</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Alex

Comment: Have you tried to push an event to the dataLayer with the signup success page? You can then set up a rule to fire on that event.

What does your {{success message}} macro return? It looks like it should be returning an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I have to do this a lot for my clients and the following seems to work for me. **NOTICE: This solution utilizes jQuery.**

The idea is that you want to run a script that checks to see if the success message is visible, when it becomes visible, push a dataLayer event to the GTM (Google Tag Manager).

Step One, create a custom HTML tag in the GTM console that fires a dataLayer event when the success message becomes visible:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    try{
        // Set a variable to the setInterval method so it can be cleared.
        var checkSuccess = setInterval(function(){
            // Check if the success message exists.
            if($('span:contains(Thank you for signing up)').length !== 0){
                // Check if the success message is visible.
                if($('span:contains(Thank you for signing up)').is(':visible')){
                    // Push the success event to the GTM's dataLayer.
                    dataLayer.push({'event' : 'signUpSuccess'});  
                    // Terminate the interval upon success.
                    clearInterval(checkSuccess);
                }
            }
        },500);
    }catch(e){
      // Uncomment to view errors.
      // console.log('GTM Error: ' + e);
    }
})();
</script>
```

Notice that I didn't use document ready. That's because this tag should only fire upon event = gtm.load in GTM, which will serve the same purpose. Specifically, the following firing rule should be appropriate

```
{{url}} - ends with - /artistsignup/index/index
{{event}}} - equals - gtm.load
```

Finally, any tracking tags that you want to fire when the success message appears should have the following rule:

```
{{event}} - equals - signUpSuccess
```

Final note, if you can't use jQuery for this, then just replace the jQuery selectors with a pure JavaScript selector.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this! Really appreciate your help. As a jQuery novice I'm not sure how to solve the following javascript compiler error - "Error at line 12, character 6: Parse error. '}' expected." (This relates to line "}catch(e){"). Any advice would, again, be massively appreciated!

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I'm not getting a javascript compiler error when I try it in my test GTM contianer. Could you provide an exact copy of the tag you created? In my example, line 12 is commented out with "// Terminate the interval..."